# Fractional Calculator help in JAVA

Tags: java, calculator

I am working on a fractional calculator and below is what I have so far. I am stuck at the reducing part, but I do not know how I would create this to print out the answer. Also, if anything else is wrong with my code please let me know. This calculator should take input like: 2/7 and 6/7 and an operator like + and this should print out: 1_1/7. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculator {
    String operator;
    String int1;
    String int2;
    public static int whole1;
    public static int whole2;
    public static int num1;
    public static int num2;
    public static int den1;
    public static int den2;
    public static void main (String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, I'm a fractional calculator. FracCalc for short.");
        Scanner everything = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your first number type:");
            String int1 = everything.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            String int2 = everything.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter operation (+, *, -, /):");
            String operator = everything.nextLine();
    }

public static void fractionFormat (String int1, String int2, String operator) {
    if (int1.contains("_")) { //first number
        whole1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(0, int1.indexOf("_")));
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(int1.indexOf("_") + 1, int1.indexOf("/")));
        den1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(int1.indexOf("/") + 1));
        num1 = (whole1*den1)+num1;
    }
    else if (int1.contains("/")) {
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(0, int1.indexOf("/")));
        den1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(int1.indexOf("/") + 1));
    }
    else {
        whole1 = Integer.parseInt(int1.substring(0));
        whole1 = num1;
        den1 = 1;
    }


    if (int2.contains("_")) { //second number
        whole2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(0, int2.indexOf("_")));
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(int2.indexOf("_") + 1, int2.indexOf("/")));
        den2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(int2.indexOf("/") + 1));
        num2 = (whole2*den2)+num2;
    }
    else if (int2.contains("/")) {
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(0, int2.indexOf("/")));
        den2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(int2.indexOf("/") + 1));
    }
    else {
        whole2 = Integer.parseInt(int2.substring(0));
        whole2 = num2;
        den2 = 1;
    }
    math(operator, num1, den1, num2, den2);
}
public static void math(String operator, int num1, int den1, int num2, int den2) {

    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println(addmath(num1, num2, den1, den2)); }
    else if (operator.equals("-")) {
        num2 = -1*num2;
        System.out.println(addmath(num1, num2, den1, den2)); }
    else if (operator.equals("*")) {
        System.out.println(multmath(num1, num2, den1, den2)); }
    else {
        System.out.println(multmath(num1, num2, den1, den2)); }
    }

public static String addmath(int num1 , int num2 , int den1 , int den2) {
    int newnum = (num1*den2) + (num2*den1);
    int newden = den1*den2;
    String answer = reduce(newnum, newden);;
    return answer; }

public static String multmath(int num1 , int num2 , int den1 , int den2) {
    int newnum = num1 * num2;
    int newden = den1 * den2;
    String answer = reduce(newnum, newden);
    return answer;  }
```

Comment: Where is the call for the method in the main ?

Answer (score 0):

You missing two things,

The call for the method, (as asked by Manuel Mejias ),

So you should ad this at the end of your main method : 
fractionFormat(int1, int2,operator);

Also, the method reduce "String answer = reduce(newnum, newden);" is not defined... you didn't paste all the code ?